# "COM Surrogate stopped working" error

Tags: com, windows-vista

How can I fix the error "COM Surrogate stopped working" in Windows Vista Business?

Answer (score -1):

- Right click My Computer, select
  Properties - select Advanced System
  Settings from the left side pane -
- In the Performance box, Click
  Settings - Click Data Execution
  Prevention tab.
- Check the "Turn on DEP for all
  programs and services except those I
  select" option - Click "Add".
- A navigation box opens, navigate to
  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllhost.exe`,
  Click it to add and hit OK.
- This should now add this "Com
  Surrogate", with a checked box, into
  the list area, OK out, reboot and
  you're done. The Com Surrogate errors
  should disappear

Taken from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/8625c34c-300b-45ed-8d9c-d22104e83fe3)

Answer (score -1):

This process nowadays is often caused by the trojan. Check your PC with anti-malware. These intruders got smart and tend to disguise their malicious activity behind these common exe processes, in this case, Dllhost.exe. check in which folder this file is and maybe update the program or drivers it is linked to. It may be an outdated software issue too.